# Cannot add vertical line(divider) in TableLayout Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, tablelayout, android-tablet-layout

i need to add vertical border in TableLayout. I have searched the internet and tried many solutions but none of them are working. Below is my code:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/row"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:showDividers="beginning"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:stretchColumns="1"
android:background="@drawable/custom_background">

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="Name"
        android:padding="3dip" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Imran"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>

<View
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:background="#FF909090" />

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="Name"
        android:padding="3dip" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Test"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>

<View
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:background="#FF909090" />

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="Name"
        android:padding="3dip" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Test"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>
```

I am getting this with the above code
[TableLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPqYu.png)

But i need to add vertical line(Border) in front of "Name". I have tried adding View between two textViews in a TableRow but that stretches the whole column even if i set the width to 1dip.
Any Suggestions on how to add the vertical border?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about android except that I have android developer with me. You can have verticle line by a box having width of 1px (or the width you desire) infront of the name. Hope this works for you.

Comment: As i have already wrote in my post that i have tried creating a view of 1dip width but it stretches the whole column.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. any solution found?